# Custom gradle plugin throws Unable to load class 'io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph'

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin, classgraph

I'm using the [ClassGraph library](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph) inside a custom gradle plugin: https://github.com/RoRoche/plantuml-gradle-plugin/tree/feature/using_classgraph

It's OK during unit testing and while releasing into local Maven and used in another project.

But since it has been released to gradle plugin portal (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.roroche.plantuml), when using inside another project (https://github.com/RoRoche/eo-plantuml-builder), when running my `buildClassDiagram` task, it throws

```sh
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':buildClassDiagram'.
> Lio/github/classgraph/ClassGraph;
```

Any idea of what's going wrong? Gradle plugin packaging?

Update with stacktrace option

```sh
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':buildClassDiagram'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$$Lambda$395/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$$Lambda$315/0000000000000000.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.readFields(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:346)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.lambda$createJavaClass$20(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:313)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder$$Lambda$305/0000000000000000.apply(Unknown Source)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.createJavaClass(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:313)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.lambda$readClasses$19(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:305)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder$$Lambda$304/0000000000000000.accept(Unknown Source)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.readClasses(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:305)
        at ch.ifocusit.plantuml.classdiagram.ClassDiagramBuilder.build(ClassDiagramBuilder.java:153)
        at com.github.roroche.plantuml.diagrams.ClassDiagram.<init>(ClassDiagram.kt:28)
        at com.github.roroche.plantuml.diagrams.ClassDiagram.<init>(ClassDiagram.kt:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at com.github.roroche.plantuml.tasks.BuildClassDiagramTask.execute(BuildClassDiagramTask.groovy:60)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:727)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:694)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$$Lambda$360/0000000000000000.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep$$Lambda$354/0000000000000000.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep$$Lambda$338/0000000000000000.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.github.classgraph.ClassGraph
        ... 113 more
```

Here are the steps to reproduce:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/RoRoche/plantuml-gradle-plugin
$ git fetch
$ git checkout feature/using_classgraph
```

Then in the `build.gradle` file, change the line 18 to set the version you want.

Then publish it to local Maven using `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

In another Gradle-based project, define the Local Maven repository for plugin management in `settings.gradle` such as:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

Then, in the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.roroche.plantuml" version "{version}"
}

classDiagram {
    packageName = "{your_package}"
    outputFile = project.file('diagrams/class_diagram.plantuml')
}
```

And launch task `./gradlew buildClassDiagram`

Here are debug logs of the task execution:

```sh
2020-05-07T13:18:29.039+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute execute for :buildClassDiagram' started
2020-05-07T13:18:29.040+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Package to scan: com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder
2020-05-07T13:18:29.040+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Output file: /Users/Romain/GitHub/eo-plantuml-builder/diagrams/class_diagram.plantuml
2020-05-07T13:18:29.040+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Classes to ignore: [com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.Classes$Simple, com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.diagrams.Diagram$Wrap, com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.diagrams.Diagram$Simple, com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.Classes$Wrap]
2020-05-07T13:18:29.040+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] URLs to scan: [file:/Users/Romain/GitHub/eo-plantuml-builder/build/classes/java/main, file:/Users/Romain/GitHub/eo-plantuml-builder/build/classes/kotlin/main/]
2020-05-07T13:18:29.738+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Task] Classes to print in class diagram: [interface com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.Classes, class com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.ClsFiltered, class com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.ClsInPackage, class com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.ClsWithNames, class com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.classes.exceptions.InvalidPackageException, class com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.diagrams.ClassDiagram, interface com.github.roroche.eoplantumlbuilder.diagrams.Diagram]
```

Comment: Did u try with --stacktrace and/or --debug to see what's happening ?

Comment: Other question : how do u configure dependency to classgraph : implementation("") ?

Comment: I include it such as

`
implementation 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.12'
`

(maybe a module issue: https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/wiki#use-as-a-module)

Comment: Same issue when compiling with JDK8 :'(

Comment: Seeing stacktrace, it seems that plantuml doesn't have access to ClassGraph, classpath problem ? Maybe issue on reflection use or initialization of plantuml ?

Comment: Why plantuml needs classgraph?

Comment: Actually, I use the following library: https://github.com/jboz/plantuml-builder

And here is the code the add classes to the diagram buidler:

```
Diagram.Simple(
            builder.addClasse(
                classes.list()
            ).build()
        )
```

It seems that when ClassDiagramBuilder.readFields, it throws. But why on class ClassGraph?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the comment on this Gradle discussion: https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph/issues/427#issuecomment-625211790